# Signing the inconsistency of a control functions estimator with an incomplete set of instruments

Tags: econometrics, probit, instrumental-variables, endogeneity, errors-in-variables

I've got a model of the form
$$
y = 1\left(\alpha+\delta x+\beta_1\tilde v+\tilde\epsilon>0\right)
$$

$x$ is endogenous, and $\tilde v$ is a control function residual:
$$
\tilde v = x-Z'^{inc}\tilde\gamma
$$
where $Z^{inc}$ are an incomplete set of instrumental variables.  The complete set $Z^c$ is complete in the sense that 
$$
\hat v = x-Z'^c\hat\gamma
$$
such that 
$$
y = 1\left(\alpha+\delta x+\beta_1\hat v+\epsilon>0\right)
$$
renders $x$ orthogonal to $\epsilon$ -- it "controls" for the endogeneity in $x$.

In the first equation, probit estimators of $\delta$ and $\beta_1$ will be inconsistent.

How can I sign the inconsistency?  So far, I've written this as an error-in-variables model:
$$
y = 1\left(\alpha+\delta x+\beta_1\left(\tilde v-(Z'^{inc}\tilde\gamma-Z'^{c}\hat\gamma)\right)+\epsilon>0\right) = 1\left(\alpha+\delta x+\beta_1\tilde v+\left(\epsilon-\beta_1(Z'^{inc}\tilde\gamma-Z'^{c}\hat\gamma)\right)>0\right)
$$

Given that instruments have to be exogenous, I'm pretty sure that $E(Z'^{inc}\tilde\gamma-Z'^{c}\hat\gamma)=0$

Intuition says that $\delta$ will be attenuated, because "there is more error term left un-sopped-up by the control function".  But could there be systematic bias also, which would depend on which $Z$ are excluded from $Z^c$?  My instinct says yes, particularly if some $Z$ are positively correlated with $x$, and others are negatively correlated.  But I can't figure out how to show this.